# Some syntax change in jsp from struts1 to struts2 --> logic:messagesPresent

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have below code. How to handle in struts2 of `logic:messagesPresent` which is  for checking the property and display the `<tld:label id="changepwd.error.info1" /`> which is my jsp tag library and I think it can remain in struts2 as I have tested it can show the text.

```
<logic:messagesPresent property="error.message.missingNewPassword">
        <tld:label id="changepwd.error.info1" />
</logic:messagesPresent>
```

Answer (score 2):

`logic:messagesPresent` can be used only Struts 1.x.

You can use `hasActionMessages()` or `hasActionErrors()` instead of it, for example:

```
<s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
   <tld:label id="changepwd.error.info1" />
</s:if>
```

Comment: Can I check the property of "error.message.missingNewPassword" in logic:messagesPresent?

Comment: `hasKey("error.message.missingNewPassword")` may be able to used.